# After a long-running adapter call I get a WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED event on my device

Tags: networking, connection, ibm-mobilefirst, performance-testing

Worklight 6.1.0

I have a long running adapter call (runs for about 140 seconds), then on the next adapter call, my callback that I've defined to handle the WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED event is triggered.

This isn't reproducible from my emulator, only from a real device on wireless, which makes me think it's a networking issue, but it is curious that it always happens after this long-running adapter call in front of it.

I don't see anything interesting in the Worklight Server log after the invokation.  Is there a good trace setting that I could turn up that might give me more connection information from the Worklight Server?

My adapter invokation passes a timeout of 360 seconds into the call:

```
{"adapter":"OSLCGenericAdapter","procedure":"query","parameters":[{"url":"....
```

Sample log from the failed invokation:

Unable to load remote page for workOrder, queryBase: getMyAssignedWork, Error: {"invocationContext":null,"errorCode":"UNRESPONSIVE_HOST","errorMsg":"The service is currently not available."}
05-22 14:40:27.853: E/Web Console(14273): Unable to load remote page for workOrder, queryBase: getMyAssignedWork, Error: {"invocationContex

Comment: My I suggest to rethink what it is that you are trying to fetch? perhaps you should fetch only what you need and not everything? try to minimize the duration.

Comment: Probably will not help, but just to be aware of the article below: heartbeat is if your app goes to the background and server session timeout default is 10 minutes, assuming you have not changed. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_optimizing_and_tuning_of_ibm_wl_server.html?lang=en

Comment: Is this a production environment? Do you have a firewall between the server and the database/backend?

Comment: The server and database are on the same system.  This is a test environment.  
Unfortunately I have to load this information up front into the application.

Answer (score 1):

As @IdanAdar pointed out, having a request this long probably means you should rethink how you approach this problem, my suggestion is you separate the data preparation from the data download, so the first request is short and returns a "dataId", after which the status of this  data preparation "job" is polled until ready.
This approach might also have the added benefit of providing the user with progress information (depending on the underlying technology).

One other thing that you might want to make sure is that you have a proper timeout in your adapter XML configuration (`requestTimeoutInSeconds`), which actually controls the timeout from the Worklight server to the back-end (the invocation timeout you specify on the client side is just that - client side timeout):

```
<wl:adapter .....>
   ....
    <procedure name="procName" requestTimeoutInSeconds="140"/>
</wl:adapter>
```